# Listening to PropertyChanged from another class

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

How can I listen in class B to the `PropertyChanged` events from class A? I would like to listen to changes of a property from class A.

```
class A : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        private int _x;

        public int X
        {
            get => _x;
            set
            {
                if (_x == value) return;
                _x = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(X));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
}

class B
{
        public B(int x)
        {
            // In this class I want to listen to changes of the property X from class A
        }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just listen to the event:

```
class B
{
    public A _myA;

    public B(int x)
    {
        _myA = new A();
        _myA.PropertyChanged += A_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void A_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName != nameof(_myA.X)) return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will handle all property changes. OP is interested in a specific property. How to handle changes of property `X`?

Comment: Oh sorry. I will add code to check for the property

Comment: You can just check the EventArgs to find out which property was modified. Adapted my answer with one example

Comment: I know the answer. I only wanted to point out that your answer wasn't complete.